# VB.NET - Change Style/Format of database DateTimes?

Tags: database, vb.net, datetime, ssis

I have an SSIS Script component that needs to run some VB.NET code shortly before it exports data.

I'm feeding this script component each row of a timestamp column. (datatype DT_DBTIMESTAMP)

The input style of the date is as follows: `2012-09-12 16:34:12`

I need the VB.NET code to change this so it shows in the format: `09/12/2012 04:34:12 PM`

The two key points being that all values need to be padded with a zero if they're single digits, and all time values need to be in 12 hour format with AM/PM.  In short, the style must follow:  `{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}`

Unfortunately, I have very limited VB.NET skills, and I have yet to find an example of this on SO or MSDN.  From my searching, it appears I might be able to create a new style of DateTime object and then use a custom date format or something?  I can't for the life of me figure out what to do here.

The autogenerated code from the script component is as follows:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper

Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        '
        ' Add your code here
        '
    End Sub

End Class
```

So could I do something like:

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", Row.[DateTimeColumn].toString())
```

I dunno...totally lost here.  First time using script components in SSIS or VB.NET really.

Help???? :(

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something wrong when you save back to the column. If you're doing this right, **you never mess with strings at all**. Stick entirely with the DateTime type and things will be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the data as a `Date` object, then you can simply call the `ToString` method and pass the format string, for instance:

```
Dim d As Date = columnValue
Dim formatted As String = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

However, if you get the date as a string, then you need to first parse it into a `Date` object before reformatting it:

```
Dim s As String = columnValue
Dim d As Date = Date.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim formatted As String = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Comment: You, sir, are a god among men.  Seriously though, THANK YOU SO MUCH!  Since I was getting the column values as dates, I simply had to use your first section of code, and then save "formatted" back into the column.  Wow, thank you so, so much.